# Not sure why my program keeps prompting error when I try to close it?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int add_even(int);
int add_odd(int);

int main() {
    int num, result_odd, result_even, even_count, odd_count;
    char name;

    printf("What is your name?\n");
    scanf("%s", &name);

    while (num != 0) {
        printf("Enter a number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        if (num % 2 == 1) {
            printf ("odd\n");
            odd_count++;
        } else
        if (num == 0) {
            printf("%s, the numbers you have entered are broken down as follows:\n",
                  name);
            result_even = add_even(num);
            printf("You entered %d even numbers with a total value of %d\n",
                   even_count, result_even);
            result_odd = add_odd(num);
            printf("You entered %d odd numbers with a total value of %d\n",
                   odd_count, result_odd);
        } else {
            printf("even\n");
            even_count++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
} 

int add_even(int num) {
    static int sum = 0;

    if (num % 2 != 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    sum += add_even(num);
    return sum;
}

int add_odd(int num) {
    static int sum = 0;

    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    sum += add_odd(num);
    return sum;
}
```

Can anyone give me some insight as to what I did wrong exactly?

The point of the code is to get inputs from the user until they decide to stop by inputting 0. Separating the evens from the odd. Tell them how many even/odd they put and the total of all the even/odd numbers.

I understand how to separate the evens from the odds. I think my issue is with my function.

Comment: Not obvious on a quick look.   Try (1)  cutting out code that is not related to the problem (makes it harder for others to understand what is going on)   (2)  formatting the code properly, so it is obviously (say) which `{` match which `}`.   AND (3)  Providing a sample of offending input.   Also - Initialise `num` to non-zero value before the loop (leaving it uninitialised means that accessing its value, first time into the loop, gives undefined behaviour - which doesn't tend to be helpful if trying to localise another problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `scanf()` causes undefined behavior when trying to store a string into a single character.  Pass an array and specify a maximum length.
- you should check the return value of `scanf()`: if `scanf()` fails to convert the input according to the specification, the values are unmodified, thus uninitialized, and undefined behavior ensues. In your case, if 2 or more words are typed at the prompt for the name, `scanf("%d",...)` fails because non numeric input is pending, no further characters are read from stdin and `num` is not set.
- `num` is uninitialized in the first `while (num != 0)`, causing undefined behavior.
- functions `add_even()` and `add_odd()` are only called for `num == 0`, never summing anything.
- functions `add_even()` and `add_odd()` should always return the sum and add the value of the argument `num` is it has the correct parity. They currently cause undefined behavior by calling themselves recursively indefinitely.
- `odd_count` and `even_count` are uninitialized, so the counts would be indeterminate and reading their invokes undefined behavior.

In spite of all the sources of undefined behavior mentioned above, the reason your program keeps prompting without expecting an answer if probably that you type more than one word for the name. Only a single word is converted for `%s`, leaving the rest as input for numbers, which repeatedly fails in the loop.  These failures go unnoticed as you do not verify the return value of `scanf()`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int add_even(int);
int add_odd(int);

int main(void) {
    int num, result_odd, result_even, even_count = 0, odd_count = 0;
    char name[100];

    printf("What is your name? ");
    if (scanf("%99[^\n]", name) != 1)
        return 1;

    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1 || num == 0)
            break;

        if (num % 2 == 1) {
            printf("odd\n");
            odd_count++;
            add_odd(num);
        } else {
            printf("even\n");
            even_count++;
            add_even(num);
        }
        printf("%s, the numbers you have entered are broken down as follows:\n", name);
        result_even = add_even(0);
        printf("You entered %d even numbers with a total value of %d\n",
               even_count, result_even);
        result_odd = add_odd(0);
        printf("You entered %d odd numbers with a total value of %d\n",
               odd_count, result_odd);
    }
    return 0;
} 

int add_even(int num) {
    static int sum = 0;

    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        sum += num;
    }
    return sum;
}

int add_odd(int num) {
    static int sum = 0;

    if (num % 2 != 0) {
        sum += num;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Well answered! I noticed you didn't explicitly mention the `scanf` return value in your explanation (though you accounted for this in your code), so I figured I'd mention it here: *most* standard C functions have return values for a reason, and *usually* one of those reasons is error checking. If you choose to discard error checking (e.g. by discarding the return value), strange things might happen when an error occurs.

Comment: @Seb: I added some extra details about the need to check the return value of `scanf()`.  This error ranks high among causes for newbie problems. In fact, it is a very common source of bugs for all users of `scanf()`.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I was far more in the red than I thought. Still new, so trying to figure all of it out is kinda hard, but thanks for the insight. I see where I went wrong, I'll try to keep those things in mind.

Comment: @KentGrayden: keep working on this, the effort is well rewarded.  You can accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

You declared:

```
char name;                       // One single letter, such as 'A', or 'M'

printf("What is your name?\n");  // Please enter a whole bunch of letters!
scanf("%s", &name);              // Not enough space to store the response!
```

---

What you really want is more like

```
char name[31];                   // Up to 30 letters, and an End-of-String marker

printf("What is your name?\n"); // Please enter a whole bunch of letters!
scanf("%s", name);              // name is the location to put all those letters
                                // (but not more than 30!)
```

Comment: This is only a partial fix: `if (scanf("%29s", name) != 1) return 1;` is a safer solution.